# Saving state while changing back and forth to a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am writing an app that is essentially a card that can be flipped.Both side have certain relevant data say hint on one side and picture on another.Both sides of data are related.My problem is i can navigate through the cards by clicking next but when i flip the card for picture, i get back to the beginning since the first activity is reloaded.How can i solve the issue? My code is:
package org.v2.greTouch;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FlipCard extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 Cursor cur;
TextView tv;
DbH db;
ImageButton next,back;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV_Word);
    next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);
    back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    LinearLayout turn;
    turn=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL_Card);
    turn.setOnClickListener(this);
    try {
        db=new DbH(this);
    } catch (IOException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


        try {
            db.createdatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     db.opendatabase();
     cur=db.data();
     cur.moveToFirst();
     tv.setText(cur.getString(0));

 }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.next :
    if(cur.isLast())
    {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        tv.setText(""+cur.getString(0));
    }
    else
    {
        cur.moveToNext();
    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(0));

    }
break;
case R.id.back:
{
    if(cur.isFirst())
    {
        cur.moveToLast();
        tv.setText(""+cur.getString(0));
    }
    else {cur.moveToPrevious();
    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(0));
    }
    break;
}
case R.id.LL_Card:
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,FlashCard_back.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
}
}
```

The other side that is loaded is :

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.widget.TextView;
    public class FlashCard_back extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_back);
    LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.FlashCardRear);
    layMain.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
     public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this,FlipCard.class);
    startActivity(i);
     }
     }
```

I want that when i filp back i should get the same card awith values extracted from database.
Pls help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use ViewFlipper to flip the screen display.for that do as following in a single xml file,

```
<ViewFlipper>
    <LinearLayout>
          //front page's elements
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
         //back page's elements
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 0):

With views there is no other way than to save the data before a flip. You could save the data in a sharedpreference or in plain variables. But this is how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity rather than calling:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this,FlipCard.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Try this instead:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}
```